# 検索エンジンの検索結果に表示されるメニューの作り方

Tags: javascript, html

[image: ヤフーでgoogleと調べたとき]
ヤフーでgoogleと調べたとき、「Googleニュース」や「Google翻訳」のメニューが表示されるのですが、これはどのようにして実装するのでしょうか。

[image: グーグルでgoogleと調べたとき]
こちらは、グーグルでgoogleと調べたときです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「サイトリンク」と呼ばれている物です。
自動で作成されています。コントロールするのは難しいです。SEOの人達は頑張っているようですが。

> 現時点では、サイトリンクは自動化されています。Googleではサイトリンクのアルゴリズムを改善できるよう常に努力しており、将来は、ウェブマスターによる入力を取り入れる可能性もあります。
>   [サイトリンク - Search Console ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=ja)